# Dialog changes after user prompt

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have a dialog as follows to get user name and password from user

```
bot.dialog('/getUsernamePassword', [
function (session) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Please enter your username');
},
function (session, results) {
    session.userData.name = results.response;
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'Please enter your password');
},
function (session, results) {
    session.userData.password = results.response;
    session.endDialogWithResult(results);
}
]);
```

After user enter username, my dialog doesn't continue, instead it goes to root dialog and prints "I didn't understand please try again"(default message)

Can anyone help me to understand what I am doing wrong here?

my recognizers are configured as follows

```
var model = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/..;
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model);
bot.recognizer(recognizer);
// Add regular expression recognizer to bot
var helpRecognizer = new builder.RegExpRecognizer('HelpIntent', /^(help|options)/i);
var cancelRecognizer = new builder.RegExpRecognizer( "CancelIntent", /^(cancel|nevermind)/i);
bot.recognizer(helpRecognizer);
bot.recognizer(cancelRecognizer);
var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({ recognizers: [helpRecognizer,cancelRecognizer,recognizer] });
```

Comment: In addition to Ezequiel's answer, you probably should not be plugging your recognizers into the bot and then using an IntentDialog. Are you using the IntentDialog in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what is happening is that your response is going through `LUIS`.

In order to avoid this, update your definition of the `LuisRecognizer` to be the following:

```
var model = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/..;
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model).onEnabled((context, callback) => {
    var enabled = context.dialogStack().length === 0;
    callback(null, enabled);
});
bot.recognizer(recognizer);
```