# Does WebChat behave differently to Emulator?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

Hopefully a fairly straight-forward question.

Does the BotBuilder Emulator behave differently to WebChat? For example, I currently use the following snippet to welcome the user and immediately direct them into a Dialog:

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (message) {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
      message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
        if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
          var msg = new builder.Message()
            .address(message.address)
            .text('Hi, I\'m ChatBot. Let\'s get your number activated!')
          bot.send(msg)
          setTimeout(() => {
            bot.beginDialog(message.address, 'ActivateNumber:/')
          }, 1000)
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

The dialog users a Choice Prompt to direct the user to the relevant information. The emulator and WebChat both display this Prompt perfectly. When the user clicks on a choice button, the emulator passes the results into the next function in the waterfall as expected, however, WebChat appears to be trying to pass this value into an IntentDialog and querying LUIS. It's almost like WebChat has left the dialog for some reason (the code for which is below):

```
lib.dialog('/', [
  function (session, args) {
    builder.Prompts.choice(session, 'OK, which of these best describes you?', ['Testing', 'Testing', 'Testing', 'Testing'], {listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button})
  },
  function (session, results, next) {
    console.log(results)
  }
])
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: Does this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354323/dialog-changes-after-user-prompt

Comment: Thanks @EzequielJadib. Will give this a try tomorrow!

Comment: @EzequielJadib I'm afraid no luck on that front. I've stripped out everything to do with Luis, and the response to the choice prompt is now trying to route back to the '/' dialog for some reason.