# Prompt for Text Without Routing

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-language-understanding

What I'd like to incorporate into my bot is a way to prompt the user for essentially free-form, natural language text and then save it.

I thought this would be simple enough using:

```
builder.Prompts.text(session, prompt);
```

But it appears the UniversalBot is attempting to interpret and route based on the text supplied by the user.

I do have LUIS wired into the bot as the recognizer and it's clear that's what is coming into play here because it's resolving to one of my defined intents.  Or at least it's saying it recognizes that intent but it doesn't actually take the user to that dialog.

Is there some way to achieve what I'm after?  Essentially disabling the recognizer while receiving the response to a prompt?

I'm coding in Node.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dialog changes after user prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44354323/dialog-changes-after-user-prompt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the LuisRecognizer by using `.onEnabled()`. You can find an example [**here**](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/feature-onEnabled/app.js) on it in action. You'll need a condition to to enable and disable the LuisRecognizer, which could be checking the dialogStack, or setting a property inside of `session.conversationData`.

Alternatively, if you're okay with triggering the `None` intent, you can use `.onFilter()`. This will allow you to change the recognized intent to the `None` intent. Your condition here would be checking to make sure the dialogStack is empty. You can find an example for `onFilter()` [**here**](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/feature-onFilter/app.js).

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!